# Show that given a partial order there exists a total order

Tags: logic

**STATEMENT:** Suppose that $≺$ is a partial ordering of $\mathbb{N}$. Use the Compactness Theorem for first order logic to show that there is a total ordering $≺_∗$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all n and m in $\mathbb{N}$,if $n≺m$ then $n≺_∗ m.$

**QUESTION:** I am unsure of how to proceed with this type of problem. My guess was to create a set of sentences such that $(\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}(n≺m \rightarrow n≺_∗ m)$ union with another set of sentences $(\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}((m\not≺ n) \wedge (\forall k\in\mathbb{N}(k≺m\rightarrow k≺n))\rightarrow m≺_*n).$ Then showing that each finite subset is satisfiable means that our set of sentences has a model $(\mathbb{N},≺_*)$.

Comment: Using Zorn's lemma you can show that every partial ordering can be extended to total ordering, no matter the set.

Comment: I know how to prove it using Zorn's lemma, but I don't know how to prove it using compactness theorem.

Comment: I don't know too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine, however, I would use a differed set of sentences, such as (for all $n,m,k\in\mathbb N$)

- $n\prec m\to n\prec_*m$
- $\neg (n\prec_* n)$
- $n\prec_*m\lor m\prec_*n\lor n=m$
- $n\prec_*m\land m\prec_*k\;\to\; n\prec_*k$

which jointly precisely state that $\prec_*$ extends $\prec$, is irreflexive, total, and transitive.

Given only a finite set of these sentences, they involve only finitely many numbers. On these, we can perform a topological sort according to $\prec$ and use the result to defined a total order $\prec_*$ extending $\prec$ on this finite set.

If topological sort sounds like too much borrowing from the Computer Science department, you may want to prove

> **Lemma.** If $X$ is a nonempty finite set partially ordered by $\prec$, then there exists $x\in X$ such that $\forall y\in X\colon x\not\prec y$.

and use this to show by induction on the size of the set that every partial order on a finite set can be extended to a total order.